# No sound in right speaker when using headphones in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, headphones

Today suddenly, I get no sound from my right earpiece while using headphones (it works fine without them).  My headphones are not the problem either, I just tried them with my phone and they play from both ears just fine.  In 14.04 there was a persistent problem with Ubuntu where I would never get any sound while using headphones, but I never found the solution to that and assumed they fixed it in 16.04.  Is this still broken?  When I first noticed it, I immediately tried to test the sound and got faint sound in the right speaker that didn't increase if I moved the balance towards the right, but shortly after that I got none at all.

Comment: This question appears to be a bug report, and if so is [off-topic](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/), thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to blow out the port with a straw and blow really hard.

Comment: You mean the jack?  There's nothing in there, the plug goes all the way in.

Comment: but there might be dust particles inside that prohibit the connection.

Comment: Hey, thanks, that actually worked.  Didn't know that could happen.